# Cloud Firestore Security Rules permission

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-security

How can I log user information into databases and enable user permissions to write to databases during registration.

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /Users/{userId} {
  // Anybody can write to their ouser doc
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I can not register the user with these restrictions, how can I set good restrictions to enable logging information after confirmation email?

```
 register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         if (imageUri != null) {
          username_ = username.getText().toString();
          name_ = name.getText().toString();
          email_ = email.getText().toString();
          pass_ = password.getText().toString();
          location_ = location.getText().toString();

          mDialog.show();

          if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username_)) {

           AnimationUtil.shakeView(username, RegisterActivity.this);
           mDialog.dismiss();

          }

          if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name_)) {

           AnimationUtil.shakeView(name, RegisterActivity.this);
           mDialog.dismiss();

          }
          if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email_)) {

           AnimationUtil.shakeView(email, RegisterActivity.this);
           mDialog.dismiss();

          }
          if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass_)) {

           AnimationUtil.shakeView(password, RegisterActivity.this);
           mDialog.dismiss();

          }

          if (TextUtils.isEmpty(location_)) {

           AnimationUtil.shakeView(location, RegisterActivity.this);
           mDialog.dismiss();

          }

          if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name_) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(email_) ||
           !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass_) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(username_) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(location_)) {

           firebaseFirestore.collection("Usernames")
            .document(username_)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < DocumentSnapshot > () {
             @Override
             public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
              if (!documentSnapshot.exists()) {
               registerUser();
              } else {
               Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               AnimationUtil.shakeView(username, RegisterActivity.this);
               mDialog.dismiss();
              }
             }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
             @Override
             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
             }
            });

          } else {

           AnimationUtil.shakeView(username, RegisterActivity.this);
           AnimationUtil.shakeView(name, RegisterActivity.this);
           AnimationUtil.shakeView(email, RegisterActivity.this);
           AnimationUtil.shakeView(password, RegisterActivity.this);
           AnimationUtil.shakeView(location, RegisterActivity.this);
           mDialog.dismiss();

          }

         } else {
          AnimationUtil.shakeView(profile_image, RegisterActivity.this);
          Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "We recommend you to set a profile picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          mDialog.dismiss();
         }

        }
       });


       }
```

> Registering a user

```
       private void registerUser() {

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_, pass_).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task < AuthResult > task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {

           Map < String, Object > usernameMap = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
           usernameMap.put("username", username_);

           firebaseFirestore.collection("Usernames")
            .document(username_)
            .set(usernameMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Void > () {
             @Override
             public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
              task.getResult()
               .getUser()
               .sendEmailVerification()
               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Void > () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                 final String userUid = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                 final StorageReference user_profile = storageReference.child(userUid + ".png");
                 user_profile.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
```

> image upload

```
                  @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    user_profile.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Uri > () {
                     @Override
                     public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                      //noinspection deprecation
                      String token_id = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                      Map < String, Object > userMap = new HashMap < > ();
                      userMap.put("id", userUid);
                      userMap.put("name", name_);
                      userMap.put("image", uri.toString());
                      userMap.put("email", email_);
                      userMap.put("bio", getString(R.string.default_bio));
                      userMap.put("username", username_);
                      userMap.put("location", location_);
                      userMap.put("token_id", "");
```

> verification of email

```
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Verification email sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                       }
                      }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                      });

                     }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                      mDialog.dismiss();
                     }
                    });


                   } else {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                   }
                  }
                 });

                }
               })
               .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                 task.getResult().getUser().delete();
                }
               });
             }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
             @Override
             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
             }
            });


          } else {
           mDialog.dismiss();
           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
         }
        });

       }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the folloing lines of code:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Which basically means you can create user document if `request.auth.uid != null` and you can read, update, delete only if `request.auth.uid == userId`.

**Edit:**

You are getting that `PERMISSION_DENIED` warning because before trying to write to:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userUid).set(userMap)
```

You are also trying to write data to:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Usernames").document(username_).set(usernameMap)
```

Where you have no permission. Please add the corresponding permissions to the first write operation and everything will be fine.

Comment: When you sign up, get this warning

      E/Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
      V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Registration by : Realtime databse is ok 
Registration by : cloud firestory Unsuccessful!

Comment: In this case, please add the code that you are using to add the user to the database and a screenshot of your database schema.

Comment: I added the photo to the question, could not I add it in the comment?

Comment: A screenshot of your database strucuture not of your rules. Please select database TAB. Please also add the code that I was asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I do not speak fluent English, the databases are currently empty, I've added the code .

Comment: I will modify the permissions and change some commands in the code and try again, thanks for your Help with me

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: I apologize for the delay, the answer was very good, which made me late to reply that I was looking for how to confirm e-mail when logging in via Facebook, I have to send an e-mail verification message or I can skip verification normally

Comment: Thank you for following up the problem with me

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the verification part, you should post another fresh question so people who know that answer can help you.

Comment: Well, I'll post a new question if I can not deal with the problem, thank you very much